# How to compute accuracy of CNN in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, classification, convolution

I am new to TensorFlow. I am doing a binary classification with my own dataset. However I do not know how to compute the accuracy. Can anyone please help me with to do this?

My classifier has 5 convolutional layers followed by 2 fully connected layers. The final FC layer has an output dimension of 2 for which I have used:

```
prob = tf.nn.softmax(classification_features, name="output")
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific on how your classifier looks like?

Comment: My classifier has 5 convolutional layers followed by 2 fully connected layers. The final FC layer has an output dimension of 2 for which I have used `prob = tf.nn.softmax(classification_features, name="output")`

Comment: Oh awesome. Thank you :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just calculate the percentage of correct predictions:

```
prediction = tf.math.argmax(prob, axis=1)
equality = tf.math.equal(prediction, correct_answer)
accuracy = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.cast(equality, tf.float32))
```

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE 2020-11-23 Keras in Tensorflow

Now you can just specify you want it in the `metrics` parameter in `model.compile`.

This post is from 3.6 years ago when tensorflow was still in version 1.  Now that Tensorflow.org suggests using the Keras calls you can specify you want accuracy like so:

```
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='sgd',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x,y)
```

BOOM! You've got accuracy in your report when you run "model.fit".

If you are using an older version of tensorflow or just writing it from scratch, @Androbin explains it well.